# 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view to Display the below Customer Object.

```
public Class Customer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address AddressInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Address 
{
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public City CityInfo { get; set; }
    public Region RegionInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And Having an Controller to return the Customer to View

```
public ActionResult GetCustomer(long Id)
{
    return View("Customer",GetCustomer(Id));
}
```

And finally the View Is,

```
[Customer.cshtml]
@model Customer;
Name: @Model.Name
Address Details: @Html.Partial("Address",Model)

[Address.cshtml]
@model Customer;
@Model.CityInfo.Name, @Model.RegionInfo.Name
```

All seems fine. But I am getting "'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model" error on @Html.Partial("Address",Model) I had done the same before in many projects and did not got the problem.

I have no clue of further proceeding.

Could someone please help me to resolve this issue.

I have seen many posts regarding this kind of error. But those were not with the @Html.Partial().

Thanks & Regards,

Saravanakumar R.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I have resolved the issue.. Thanks for the viewers.

The problem was In my View I was using somewhere **Model => Model**. Its should be **model => model**.

Comment: I've just had the same problem, any idea WHY this is the issue... Changing the capitals has fixed this for me but I've love to know why.

Comment: Model is a property of the IView. where model is a reference of the data(model) we return from Controller Action. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `Model` is of type `Customer` rather than of type `Address` in your partial. You need to change the model type in `Address.cshtml` to `Address` and change the call to the partial to pass in the `AddressInfo` property:

```
@Html.Partial("Address", Model.AddressInfo)
```

Your view code becomes:

```
[Customer.cshtml]
@model Customer;
Name: @Model.Name
Address Details: @Html.Partial("Address",Model.AddressInfo)

[Address.cshtml]
@model Address;
@Model.CityInfo.Name, @Model.RegionInfo.Name
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I cant change the Address.cshtml model to Address since I need the values in TryUpdateModel.

Comment: You have to change it to `Address` because `CityInfo` and `RegionInfo` are properties of `Address` not `Customer`

Comment: Why are you mentioning `TryUpdateModel`? Are you trying to do model binding manually? It should be automatic