# 'Model' conflicts with the declaration in view page MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When I'm trying to do this, I'm getting a weird error.

```
<tr>
    <td>
    @Html.LabelFor(Model=>Model.Company_Name)
    </td>
    <td>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(Model=>Model.Company_Name)
    </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
       <td>
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(m=>m.LOB_NAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.LOB_NAME,Model.Lobdata) 
//Error here saying 'Model' conflicts with the declaration'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'

//Similarly when i comment the above line the error is shifting down    
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Lead_Source,Model.leadsourcedata)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873555/model-conflicts-with-the-declaration-system-web-mvc-webviewpagetmodel-model)

`Model` should be `model`
i.e

```
  @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Company_Name)
```