# accessing model in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm sure that I'm just missing something really dumb and obvious here, but I'm just at my wit's end.

I've got a view, which is strongly typed, with he code `@model Beta.Models.ResearchReportingForm` I'm just trying to access Model.ResearchReportingFormID, in the statement:

```
Html.RenderAction("EditReportListView", "researchreport", new { parentID = Model.ResearchReportingFormID });
```

Even though intellisence suggested the field information to me, I get the error:

CS0135: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model'

I've read other threads on SO, but I dunno how they apply, as I'm trying to access a model's info, but not inside a lambda. What should I do to accomplish this?

Comment: please, take a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873555/model-conflicts-with-the-declaration-system-web-mvc-webviewpagetmodel-model), probably it will help, you probably somewhere wrote: `Model => Model` instead of `model => model`, if no, please, provide full code of the view

Comment: @Sergey, I haven't actually used 'Model' in a lambda like you mentioned, however, I've worked around the problem using ViewBag. Code is here: http://pastebin.com/Bg6uMzwy (Problem on line 92)

Comment: @Jack, 1) you have to avoid of using references to others resources, as your code will be removed after some time and it will be not impossible to figure out meaning of your question, 2)I found in your code next thing: `@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.PublicationFormID);` it has to be `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PublicationFormID)`