# Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I try to check if the model.LastName is empty to set an attribute to the textBox and I get this error:
Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CellphonePrefix, new {title = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CellphonePrefix) ? "Requried" : "") })
```

the error is about the second model:

```
title = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.LastName) ? "Requried" : ""
```

the tags are inside form here the full code:

```
@model Models.UserViewModelR
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Register", "Start", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return validateForm()", lang = "he" })) 
{
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CellphonePrefix, new {title = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CellphonePrefix) ? "Requried" : "") })
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try using different identifier for binding expression e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CellphonePrefix, ...)` (seems that your current code already fixed the problem). This problem often caused by unintentionally using `Model` property in expression like this: `@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.CellphonePrefix)`.

Comment: It doesn't help. do you have any idea?

Comment: I can't reproduce in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wE7nnW). Possibly you have wrong declaration on view page but not shown on your question yet, can you provide detailed view page code? Also what `Model.LastName` belongs to?

Answer (score -1):

Change model=>model to Model=>Model  code below try this

```
@model Models.UserViewModelR
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Register", "Start", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype 
= 
"multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return validateForm()", lang = "he" })) 
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.CellphonePrefix, new {title = 
 (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CellphonePrefix) ? "Requried" : "") })
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend changing it into Model => Model because it can cause this specific conflict error, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16890535/9381487 and comments for an explanation why.